# Load text file from url into an array

Tags: c#, arrays, url

I am currently using

```
string[] defaultcommands = (File.ReadAllLines(@"commands"));
```

to load a local files contents in the solution as an array. I want to be able to update the contents of that file from my workstation and it take effect on all instances running. To do this, I'd like to load the default command file from a url like: https://mywebsite.com/assistant/commands.txt. I tried string[] defaultcommands = (File.ReadAllLines(@"https://mywebsite.com/assistant/commands.txt")); but it doesn't understand how to handle the URL I guess. It comes back with: System.NotSupportedException.

How can I load a text file from a URL into an array?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

It gives this example:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient ();
string reply = client.DownloadString (address);

Console.WriteLine (reply);
```

Comment: I get "The type or namespace WebClient could not be found." Also, 
"A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'assistant.Form1.client."

Comment: It is in `System.Net`. Have you added that namespace and reference?

Comment: I've stated "using System.Net;" in the beginning of the document. Next , under my namespace "AssistantOne" I have "public partial class Form1 : Form" then I put your "WebClient client = new WebClient(); string reply = client.DownloadString("https://mysite.com/commands.txt);" but it gives an error stating that client "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property "AssistantOne.Form1.client."

Comment: I also get "Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'string[]'

Comment: Yea, here is the entire project folder. I've used what you've told me and it fails to compile. [link](https://opticorpnm.com/JarvisOne.zip)

Comment: You have a compile error because you have not put your code inside of a method. If you are having trouble with C# syntax, please open another question and we can help you solve it there.